# Sencha app build development does not copy JS files to /build folder

Tags: extjs, build, sencha-cmd

I am working with EXTJS6/sencha cmd 6.1.
I am running `sencha app build development` on my application but it does not copy my javascript files to the build folder. I searched and learnt that QA & Production builds minifies the JS files and copy it to the build where as Development build does not. I believe, using copy task in build.xml we can copy the JS files in the build folder.

Since, the JS Files are copied in the build folder, I can not send the DEV build from build folder to Server.Can someone has an example or guide me on how to write the copy task in build.xml or are there any other alternatives?

Thanks,
gendaful

Comment: A development build does not minify the JS, but if you didn't customize the build scripts, it should aggregate all your files and the original ext files into one (possibly multi-megabyte) blob of javascript. How big is the app.js in the folder `build/development`?

Comment: @Alexander - I do no see app.js in build/development . Generally, QA/PROD build minifies your files and create an app.js out of it. But I am not sure, how to achieve this in development build. I am looking for an example to modify build.xml to copy application js files in the build/development folder.

Comment: My uncustomized development build does produce an unminified app.js file. Please have a really good look whether the build throws any errors; and check in `.sencha/development.properties` whether the build path points somewhere else.

Comment: @Alexander - Thanks for the pointers. I think we are getting closer to the solution. I do not get any build errors but as you directed, there might be buildpath missing in the development.properties. My current development.properties is empty. This file is used to override the settings specified in build.properties. Can you please point out what are your inclusions in development.properties file to copy unminified app.js to build/development folder?

Comment: If your `development.properties` is empty, your build path should be set to default values by the Sencha Cmd build scripts, and an `app.js` file should be created in folder `build/development/MyAppName/`. Do the production build and the testing build both produce javascript output in their respective build output directory?

Comment: Yes, Prd and QA builds are fine and they generate JS output in the respective folder. Only DEV is not.

Comment: I do see only /build/Development/MyApp/resources folder getting created. i do not see app.js,app.json, index.html etc created at root folder. When I create QA build, these all files are getting generated though.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that what sencha app build development has changed.  in previous versions, it created a development build directory.  Now, it just minifies the data in your root directory so that you can run it directly from there.

My workflow is now I just do "Sencha App Watch" and run from my root while doing development.  When I want to test my production build I do sencha app build production and the folder gets created as before.

HTH's.

Comment: Sorry, just tying to understand. "It minifies the data in root directory"? Where in root directory?

Comment: Sorry, I mis-spoke. I just checked my latest project that uses CMD and sencha app watch loads all the files individually (you can see the network log here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/0rjy5jgtsp5cfz7/sencha1.png?dl=0   I'm not sure how to make a minimized dev version of the source. I just read the docs here: http://docs.sencha.com/cmd/guides/extjs/cmd_app.html and it's not clear to me how to do that.  My workflow is that I do dev with sencha app watch and sencha app build production for my final product and that works well for me.  sorry

Comment: I am just trying to copy the unminified app.js to build/development folder which is not happening for me.